# Component not refreshing on firebase change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code:

```
export default class MainStudentPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {user: {nickname: '', friends: {accepted: [], invites: [], all: []}}};
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const {uid} = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        firebase.database().ref('Users').child(uid).on('value', (r, e) => {
            if (e) {
                console.log(e);
                return null;
            }
            const user = r.val();
            this.setState({user: user});
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {user} = this.state;
        return (
                <LevelSelectComponent user={user}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And this is the child:

```
export default class LevelSelectComponent extends React.Component {
    returnSelect = (user) => {
        const lvls = [{
            db: 'Podstawówka',
            text: 'PODSTAWOWA'
        }, {
            db: 'Gimnazjum',
            text: 'GIMNAZJALNA'
        }, {
            db: 'Liceum',
            text: 'ŚREDNIA'
        }];
        let options = [];
        if (!user.level) {
            options.push(<option selected={true} value={null}>WYBIERZ POZIOM</option>)
        }
        options = options.concat(lvls.map((lvl, i) => {
            return (
                <option key={i} value={lvl.db}>{`SZKOŁA ${lvl.text}`}</option>
            )
        }));
        return (
            <select defaultValue={user.level}>
                {options.map(opt => opt)}
            </select>
        )
    };
    render() {
        const {user} = this.props;
        return (
            this.returnSelect(user)
        );
    }
}
```

So what I want is to refresh the default selected value to match the value in the database. I am listening to the firebase realtime database for changes. Every time I refresh the page, the defaultValue changes, as expected, but this doesn't do it in real time. It even logs the new value, but it doesn't rerender it. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you check in React DevTools, whether the state is getting updated for the Parent component

Comment: It is. If I console.log the level in the returnSelect method in the child it is changed as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. All I had to do was change `defaultValue` to `value`

Comment: defaultValue works for the first time when you are rendering. If you want to change selected value more and more you may simply use value.

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillMount()` this should not be the method where you use AJAX requests
instead, user `componentDidMount()`.

Further:

`componentWillMount()` will only be invoked once, before the first `render()` for your component, thus it will not trigger a re-render for it, you should subscribe to your firebase realtime events in `componentDidMount()`.